# How to assert localStorage in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I worry that I'm doing this incorrectly, but the docs don't have an explicit example that I've found.

I have a test that walks thru the login flow. I also want to verify that certain values have been set inside localStorage once we're logged in.

#### When I do the following, I get an AssertionError, "expected null to exist":

```js
describe("Trying to log in...", function() {
  it("Visits the Home Page", function() {
    cy.visit("/") // Uses baseUrl prefix from config

    // [ ... snip ... ]

    // Form should be visible and fillable now!
    cy.get("form")
      .should("be.visible")
      .within(() => {
        cy.findByLabelText(/email address/i)
          .should("exist")
          .should("be.visible")
          .click() // Clicking the label should focus the element:
          .type("[test username]")
        cy.findByLabelText(/password/i)
          .click()
          .type("[test password]")
        cy.findByText(/sign in/i).click()
      })

    // Now we're logged in... 

    cy.url().should("include", "home")

    // ========= THE FOLLOWING BREAKS: =======================
    // Check for our localStorage item:
    expect(localStorage.getItem("KeyToOurValue")).to.exist()
  })
})
```

#### However, if I put that `expect` in a callback to the last `should`, it *seems* to work?

```js
describe("Trying to log in...", function() {
  it("Visits the Home Page", function() {
    cy.visit("/") // Uses baseUrl prefix from config

    // [ ... snip ... ]

    // Form should be visible and fillable now!
    cy.get("form")
      .should("be.visible")
      .within(() => {
        cy.findByLabelText(/email address/i)
          .should("exist")
          .should("be.visible")
          .click() // Clicking the label should focus the element:
          .type("[test username]")
        cy.findByLabelText(/password/i)
          .click()
          .type("[test password]")
        cy.findByText(/sign in/i).click()
      })

    // Now we're logged in... 

    cy.url().should("include", "home", ()=> {
        // ========= THE FOLLOWING WORKS! ========
        // Check for our localStorage item:
        expect(localStorage.getItem("KeyToOurValue")).to.exist()
    })
  })
})
```

#### Is that how I should do this?

It seems like I should be able to do it the first way?

What's the correct way to asset something about localStorage values after a certain `cy` line has run?

Comment: The advice in the accepted answer is spot on, however, the code above here did not work for me. When my assertions ran .to.exist() was not a function, so I ended up having to do expect(localStorage.getItem("KeyToOurValue")).to.be.a("string") or expect(localStorage.getItem("KeyToOurValue")).to.be.a("undefined") for the absence of a value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Should you assert localStorage inside the should block? Yes, you should. [Check out the official example from Cypress](https://example.cypress.io/commands/local-storage)

---

For **cy-commands** (cy.put, cy.get ...), they're enqueued and runs one after another later by Cypress. On the other hand, **non cy-commands** (expect) are executed right away. Hence, your localStorage is not available if you leave **expect** outside **should()** because **sign-in** is not finished yet.

By moving **expect** inside **should**, that means it's run after **cy.url()** is done. Since **cy.url** is the last item in Cypress' internal queue, the other cy commands (cy.visit, cy.get, cy.findBy...) have been completed by this point.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! It covered things that aren't obvious in the surface level docs, like that *expect*s might get into race conditions. Perhaps that's more general knowledge to those better-versed in Javascript testing. This was excellent! Thanks!

Comment: link is not working anymore